# Controlling number of cores being employed by parallel_run function of Scilab

Tags: parallel-processing, scilab

How can I set the number of cores parallel_run function of Scilab uses?

Answer (score 1):

From the [parallel_run documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/parallel_run.html):

> **Tuning the Parallelization with Configuration Parameters**
>
> As we have seen in the calling sequence, it is possible to add a
>   configuration parameter as a last argument to parallel_run. This
>   argument is handled by the params module and created with `init_param()`
>   (further information on how to handle parameters can be found in the
>   help pages of `add_param`, `set_param` and `remove_param`).
>
> **Number of workers**
>
> The number of computing resources used in parallel can be set by the
>   parameter nb_workers. The default value (0) uses as many workers as
>   there are cores available.

**Code sample**

```
function a=g(arg1)
  a=arg1*arg1
endfunction

res=parallel_run(1:10, g, init_param('nb_workers', 2));
```